# Why won't the recomposition trigger for my LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

I have a LazyColumn which has multiple lists which it's supposed to display depending on the `index` value. However, when I change the `index` the list changes, but the items do not get redrawn until I scroll down and back up.
I've tossed around the remember keyword, changed my logic N times and it still won't update.
Here are my classes

```
    @Composable
fun MainContent() {
    val state = homeViewModel.state.collectAsState(initial = HomepageState.Loading)
    Theme(config = config) {
        when (state.value) {
            is HomepageState.Loading -> Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) { CircularProgressIndicator() }
            is HomepageState.Multi -> with(state.value as HomepageState.Multi) {
                updateHomepageImagePreference(index)
                LazyColumnContent(homepage = items, switcher, logo, index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The homepage[index] part is the one I would like to trigger recomposition. I've tried to pass the correct list instead of changing the index, but the result is the same

```
@Composable
private fun LazyColumnContent(
    homepage: List<List<ModuleConfig>>,
    switcher: HomepageSwitcherTheme?,
    logo: HomepageThemeNavLogo?,
    index: Int = 0
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = index) {
        updateHomepageSwitcher(switcher)
        updateNavigationBarLogo(logo)
    }
    return LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(vennConfig.themeConfig.backgroundColor?.color)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(homepage[index]) { _, item ->
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                factory = {
                    val productsInCategoryCriteriaSatisfied =
                        if (item.requiresProductsInCategoryId.isNullOrEmpty()) true
                        else categoryHasProducts[item.requiresProductsInCategoryId] ?: true

                    return@AndroidView if (productsInCategoryCriteriaSatisfied) moduleFactory.build(
                        item,
                        requireContext()
                    )
                    else View(context) // blank view
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with my Compose usage, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AndroidView` `factory` is only getting called once the view appears. If you need to update `item` on the same view, you can use `update`. Also you don't need to create an empty view when you have nothing to show, just create `AndroidView` on demand:

```
val productsInCategoryCriteriaSatisfied =
    if (item.requiresProductsInCategoryId.isNullOrEmpty()) true
    else categoryHasProducts[item.requiresProductsInCategoryId] ?: true

if (productsInCategoryCriteriaSatisfied) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            moduleFactory.build(
                item,
                context
            )
        },
        update = {
            it.item = item
        },
    )
}
```

An other problem is that you may have change the items order.

The cleanest way of solving this problem is using `key` parameter: by default it's equal item index.

Perfectly your item have an `id`, but also you can build the `key` depending on any other item properties. When the `key` is not the same since the last recomposition - `AndroidView` will be re-created. p.s. when you don't need index, you can use `items` instead of `itemsIndexed`:

```
LazyColumn {
    items(list, key = { it.id }) { item ->

    }
}
```